# KnockoutJS How to add index (or different increment number) to foreach item

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I'm kinda new to KnockoutJS. I have created a custom Magento 2.3.4 extension that works as expected. I have got a template file with a table in it. It loops through a set of data and prints it out nicely. This table contains order information. One of these columns contains the order status. I want to give the parent  element a certain class, so every order line gets a different color.

This is my template file:

```html
<div class="admin__data-grid-wrap" data-role="grid-wrapper">
    <table class="data-grid" data-role="grid">
       <thead>
            <tr each="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'" render="getHeader()"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="data-row" repeat="foreach: rows, item: '$row'" id="pl_salesordergrid_color">
                <td outerfasteach="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'"
                    css="$parent.getRowClass($col,$row(),$index);" click="getFieldHandler($row())" template="getBody()"/>
            </tr>
            <tr ifnot="hasData()" class="data-grid-tr-no-data">
                <td attr="colspan: countVisible()" translate="'We couldn\'t find any records.'"/>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I know that in KnockoutJS you can work with $index or $index(). The thing i want to accomplish is to get the  element with id pl_salesordergrid_color to something like: pl_salesordergrid_color_1 but $index or $index() does not work on my first line in the foreach loop. What am i doing wrong here? Or is there a different way to accomplish?

Hopfully someone knows the answer to this. Thanks! Been at this for a whole day but i can't seem to get it to work lmao

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I just made a new function:

```html
        getTrId: function (index) {

            return 'pl_salesordergrid_color_' + index;

        },
```

Combined with this:

```html
<div class="admin__data-grid-wrap" data-role="grid-wrapper">
    <table class="data-grid" data-role="grid">
       <thead>
            <tr each="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'" render="getHeader()"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="data-row" repeat="foreach: rows, item: '$row'" data-bind="css: getTrId($index);">
                <td outerfasteach="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'"
                    css="$parent.getRowClass($col,$row(),$index);" click="getFieldHandler($row())" template="getBody()"/>
            </tr>
            <tr ifnot="hasData()" class="data-grid-tr-no-data">
                <td attr="colspan: countVisible()" translate="'We couldn\'t find any records.'"/>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This gives me the correct class on the TR so i can know which one i have to alter (add a css class so it displays the correct color).